# getElementByClassName method returns no elements

Tags: javascript

This should not be a difficult task, but for any reasons it keeps not working and I am not able to figure out why. Basically, I want to remove the paragraph with the class name "def" in the code below, but the getElementsByClassName method used in the script section seems unable to detect it, returning no elements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('def');
    alert(elems.length);
    while(elems[0]) {
        elems[0].parentNode.removeChild(elems[0]);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a title</h1>
<p>Sample paragraph</p>
<p>Another sample paragraph</p>
<p class="def"><p id="definition">Text</p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to execute code before the elements exist.

Comment: The script is executed before the document is completely read. Either put the script at the end of the document, or attach a listener and wait for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('def');
    alert(elems.length);
    while(elems[0]) {
        elems[0].parentNode.removeChild(elems[0]);
    }

</script>
```

Insert this after the HTML part.

Reason: The script is being executed before the `HTML` attributes are declared.

**EDIT**

Thanks to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355467/getelementbyclassname-method-returns-no-elements/24355490?noredirect=1#comment37658696_24355490)

Or you could use a body onload function in JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// script here
});
```

Comment: or use a body onload function // jquery '$(document).ready(function() { /* code here*/});' construct

Comment: Correct! Added it to the answer with credits ofcourse

Comment: Hi! I forgot to say that my intention is to use only native javascript functions. Now the getElementsByClassName method returns the desired element, but the script is still unable to remove the node :( any suggestions?